# How to print each row of a Dataframe including the column names?

Tags: python, pandas, printing, iteration

I have a dataframe set up as follows:

```
Project CriteriaOne CriteriaTwo CriteriaThree
Proj A  Comments A  Comments B  Comments C   
Proj B  Comments D  Comments E  Comments F   
Proj C  Comments G  Comments H  Comments I
```

I want to write to a file in the following format:

```
Proj A
Criteria One: Comments A
Criteria Two: Comments B
Criteria Three: Comments C

Proj B
Criteria One: Comments D
Criteria Two: Comments E
Criteria Three: Comments F

Proj C
Criteria One: Comments G
Criteria Two: Comments H
Criteria Three: Comments I
```

I've played with a bunch of code snippets using enumerate (yes, I know it's not 'right'), iterrows (yes, I know it's slow), and itertuples, and while I can get partial success with each, I feel like I'm overlooking something obvious.

Ideally, I'm not referencing 'CriteriaOne' by name because I'm converting a couple of different things that use the same format but 'CriteriaOne' will be named 'FlarbleOne' in another file.

I've done the other bits (consolidation of multiple rows using groupby, and the requisite file handling) but I'm just not quite getting this essential bit. What's the elegant way to iterative through this dataframe and do some nice labeling of stuff in the output?

Answer (score 1):

We can do it by iterating at each row. I am assuming you want to write it in txt file

**Data frame creation:**

```
import pandas as pd
col = ["Project", "CriteriaOne", "CriteriaTwo", "CriteriaThree"]
data = [["Proj A",  "Comments A",  "Comments B",  "Comments C"],   
["Proj B",  "Comments D",  "Comments E",  "Comments F"],
["Proj C",  "Comments G",  "Comments H",  "Comments I" ]]

df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=col)
```

**Dataframe:**

```
Project CriteriaOne CriteriaTwo CriteriaThree
0   Proj A  Comments A  Comments B  Comments C
1   Proj B  Comments D  Comments E  Comments F
2   Proj C  Comments G  Comments H  Comments I
```

**Code**

```
with open("./temp.txt", "w") as file:
    for _, row in df.iterrows():
        file.write(row[0]+"\n")
        for key, value in row[1:].items():
            file.write(key+": "+value+"\n")
        file.write("\n")
```

**Output:**

```
Proj A
CriteriaOne: Comments A
CriteriaTwo: Comments B
CriteriaThree: Comments C

Proj B
CriteriaOne: Comments D
CriteriaTwo: Comments E
CriteriaThree: Comments F

Proj C
CriteriaOne: Comments G
CriteriaTwo: Comments H
CriteriaThree: Comments I
```

Comment: This worked well — I had some issues resolving Types to get it to work and resolving some other munging I'd done, but this made it easy to tweak the final formatting and makes sense as I read it (especially as someone who used to dabble in perl). Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Suppose your dataframe is

```
f = pd.DataFrame({'A': {0: 'a', 1: 'b', 2: 'c'},'B': {0: 1, 1: 3, 2: 5},'C': {0: 2, 1: 4, 2: 6}})
```

Output:

```
   A  B  C
0  a  1  2
1  b  3  4
2  c  5  6
```

just iterating like

```
for i in f.index:
 print()
 print(i)
 for j in f.columns:
   print(f'{j} : {f.iloc[i][j]}')
```

will give output as

```
0
A : a 
B : 1 
C : 2 

1
A : b 
B : 3 
C : 4 

2
A : c 
B : 5 
C : 6
```

Answer (score 0):

Idea is convert `Project` column to `index` and loop by dictionaries create by [`DataFrame.to_dict`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_dict.html) with add values to `Series` and append to file with header:

```
df = df.set_index('Project')

with open('file.csv', 'a') as file:
    for i, j in df.T.to_dict(orient='series').items():
        s = j.index + ': ' + j
        
        file.write(f'{i}\n')
        s.to_csv(file, header=False, index=False, line_terminator='\n')
        file.write('\n')
```

Comment: I love the philosophical approach here. Now that I've gotten it working above, I want to back and play with this since it feels like the simpler model. Thanks!